# QGIS DBmanager import file append not working

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins

I am using QGIS and connecting to Postgresql database. I want to import shapefile data into database table via DBmanager tool.

But **Append data to table** selection is inactive like following image. I do not want to cerate a new database table.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]